# mySQL Using Average with Group By Function

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

I need to find the average price of a movie by genre.
The tables are Movie (movie_genre) and Price (price_rentfee)
I tried:

```
select movie_genre, avg(price_rentfee)
from movie, price
group by movie_genre;
```

It lists the movie's by genre with the avg rental fee,
but the average rental fee is the same for all of them.
Is there a way where I can average it out by genre?

Comment: What is the relationship between the table `movie` and `price`?  Where is the `JOIN` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a join, group by, and having clause. Answer i was looking for was

```
select movie_genre, avg(price_rentfee)
from price 
right join movie 
on price.price_code = movie.price_code group by movie_genre;
```

Sorry for the ambiguous question and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query says

```
FROM movie, price
```

That's probably a mistake. It generates every possible combination of movie and price.  You probably need something like this instead to get useful results.

```
FROM movie
JOIN price ON movie.movie_id = price.movie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

your query need key column to join both of tables.

```
select movie_genre, avg(price_rentfee) as avgPrice
from movie, price
where movie.movie_id = price.movie_id
group by movie_genre;
```

or

```
select movie_genre, avg(price_rentfee) as avgPrice
from movie
Left Join price
     on price.movie_id = movie.movie_id
group by movie_genre;
```